# How can I camelcase a string in php

Tags: php, regex, laravel, search, eloquent

Is there a simple way I can have php camelcase a string for me? I am using the Laravel framework and I want to use some shorthand in a search feature.

It would look something like the following...

```
private function search(Array $for, Model $in){
    $results = [];
    foreach($for as $column => $value){
        $results[] = $in->{$this->camelCase($column)}($value)->get();
    }
    return $results;
}
```

Called like

```
$this->search(['where-created_at' => '2015-25-12'], new Ticket);
```

So the resulting call in the search function I would be using is

```
$in->whereCreateAt('2015-25-12')->get();
```

The only thing is I can't figure out is the camel casing...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you considered using Laravel's built-in camel case functtion?

```
$camel = camel_case('foo_bar');
```

Full details can be found here:

https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#strings

Comment: Hahaha, I didn't even look in Laravel's helper functions. Thank you! This could have saved me a good hour of poking around online and then getting upset because I didn't find one I liked.

Answer (score 9):

So one possible solution that could be used is the following.

```php
private function camelCase($string, $dontStrip = []){
    /*
     * This will take any dash or underscore turn it into a space, run ucwords against
     * it so it capitalizes the first letter in all words separated by a space then it
     * turns and deletes all spaces.
     */
    return lcfirst(str_replace(' ', '', ucwords(preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9'.implode('',$dontStrip).']+/', ' ',$string))));
}
```

It's a single line of code wrapped by a function with a lot going on...

## The breakdown

#### What is the `dontStrip` variable?

Simply put it is an array that should contain anything you don't want removed from the camelCasing.

#### What are you doing with that variable?

We are taking every element in the array and putting them into a single string.

Think of it as something like this:

```php
function implode($glue, $array) {
    // This is a native PHP function, I just wanted to demonstrate how it might work.
    $string  = '';
    foreach($array as $element){
        $string .= $glue . $element;
    }
    return $string;
}
```

This way you're essentially gluing all your elements in your array together.

#### What's preg_replace, and what's it doing?

`preg_replace` is a function that uses a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) (also known as regex) to search for and then replace any values that it finds, which match the desired regex...

##### Explanation of the regex search

The regex used in the search above implodes your array `$dontStrip` onto a little bit `a-z0-9` which just means any letter A to Z as well as numbers 0 to 9. The little `^` bit tells regex that it's looking for anything that isn't whatever comes after it. So in this case it's looking for any and all things that aren't in your array or a letter or number.

If you're new to regex and you want to mess around with it, [regex101](https://regex101.com/) is a great place to do it.

#### ucwords?

This can be most easily though of as upper case words. It will take any word (a word being any bit of characters separated by a space) and it will capitalize the first letter.

```php
echo ucwords('hello, world!');
```

Will print `Hello, World!'

#### Okay I understand what preg_replace is, what str_replace?

`str_replace` is the smaller, less powerful but still very useful little brother/sister to `preg_replace`. By this I mean that it has a similar use. `str_replace` doesn't regex, but does use a literal string so whatever you type into the first parameter is exactly what it will look for.

*Side note, it is worth mentioning for anyone considering only using preg_replace where str_replace would work just as well. str_replace has been noted to be [benchmarked a bit faster](http://benchmarks.ro/2011/02/str_replace-vs-preg_replace/) than preg_replace on larger apps.*

#### `lcfirst` What?

Since about PHP 5.3 we have been able to use the `lcfirst` function, which much like ucwords, it's just a text manipulation function. `lcfirst turns the first letter into it's lower case form.

```php
echo lcfirst('HELLO, WORLD!');
```

Will print 'hELLO, WORLD!'

### Results

All this in mind  the camelCase function uses distinct non-alphanumeric characters as break points to turn a string to a camelCase string.

Comment: This is not camel case, but rather pascal case.
Note the difference: `pascalCase`, `CamelCase`.

Also, you have missed some cases, like if the input string is in capital letters (like a constant name). Here is a re-write of the function:
https://pastebin.com/qdDmSQUS

Answer (score 1):

There's a general purpose open source library that contains a method that performs case convertions for several popular case formats. library is called TurboCommons, and the formatCase() method inside the StringUtils does camel case conversion.

https://github.com/edertone/TurboCommons

To use it, import the phar file to your project and:

```
use org\turbocommons\src\main\php\utils\StringUtils;

echo StringUtils::formatCase('sNake_Case', StringUtils::FORMAT_CAMEL_CASE);

// will output 'sNakeCase'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Laravel's built-in camel case helper function

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
 
$converted = Str::camel('foo_bar');
 
// fooBar
```

Full details can be found here:

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-camel-case

Answer (score -1):

Use the in-built Laravel Helper Function - camel_case()

```
$camelCase = camel_case('your_text_here');
```

Comment: Only the first part of your answer is relevant to this question... ucwords only capitalizes the letter of the words after a space and at the beginning part of a string. It does not convert it to a camel case string, but your first one nails it head on :)

Comment: Actually, that was a general approach to camel casing.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase

Comment: No, using ucwords only capitalize the beginnings of words. It doesn't even remove the spacing or special characters like what we want when we reference it in programming. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase#Programming_and_coding

Comment: Yeah, thats why I said General, not specific to programming languages.
Well, hope the Laravel Helper Function works for you :)

Comment: Thank you for your contribution :D