# Switch characters case: first letter uppecase not only after space but also after slash

Tags: php, regex

I need to switch a all uppercase string text letting first letter of every word uppercase and the rest lowercas, but not after a space, also if preceeds by a slash:

Example:
TELEPHONY/MOBILE PHONE/ACCESSORIES

Should become: Telephony/Mobile Phone/Accessory

```
function upperCaseString($string)
{
$str = $string;
$arr = explode(" ", $str); // make it array

foreach($arr as &$word){ // loop array
if(!preg_match("/\d/", $word)){ // is there not a digit in the word
    $word = ucwords(strtolower($word));
}
}
echo implode(" ", $arr); // implode array to string
}
$str = "TELEPHONY/MOBILE PHONE/ACCESSORIES";

upperCaseString($str);
```

Unfortunetely it returns:
Telephony/mobile Phone/accessories

Comment: The duplicate link gives a bunch of options which should work for you.

Comment: Try my answer @Max.P.

Comment: You only split the original string by a space. Using your method, you'd need to make another array but having the string split by a slash.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34597643/how-can-i-camelcase-a-string-in-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code -

```
<?php
    echo ucwords(strtolower('TELEPHONY/MOBILE PHONE/ACCESSORIES'), "/ ");
?>
```

Output:

> Telephony/Mobile Phone/Accessories